# Multiple GestureDetector onPan event in Stack not working

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector

I have to implement a custom analog clock where the clock hands indicate the breakfast,lunch and dinner time and user is able to reset the time by rotating the hands. I was able to draw the clock and hands with the help of canvas and CustomPaint and i haved stacked up in Stack Widget.I have added GestureDetector for each hand and using onPan events am able to rotate the hands also.But the issue is that when multiple hands are put in Stack only the last added clock hand is moving with the gesture others are not detecting the gesture.How to pass down the event to the stack so that all the gesture detectors detects it?

For drawing clock hands

```
class ClockHandComponent extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  final int time;
  final Color color;

  const ClockHandComponent({Key key, this.title, this.time, this.color})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  ClockHandComponentState createState() {
    return new ClockHandComponentState();
  }
}

class ClockHandComponentState extends State<ClockHandComponent> {
  int time;
  double angle;
  ClockHandPainter _clockHandPainter;

  @override
  void initState() {
    time = widget.time;
    angle = 2 * pi / 24 * time;
    initialize();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(ClockHandComponent oldWidget) {
    initialize();
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onPanDown: _onPanDown,
      onPanUpdate: _onPanUpdate,
      onPanEnd: _onPanEnd,
      child: new Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: double.infinity,
          child: new CustomPaint(
            painter: _clockHandPainter,
          )),
    );
  }

  _onPanUpdate(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    print(details);
    RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
    var position = renderBox.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
    angle = -coordinatesToRadians(_clockHandPainter.center, position);
    print(angle);
    initialize();
    setState(() {});
  }

  _onPanEnd(_) {}

  _onPanDown(DragDownDetails details) {
    print(details);
    print(angle);
  }

  initialize() {
    _clockHandPainter =
        new ClockHandPainter(widget.title, time, widget.color, angle);
  }

  double coordinatesToRadians(Offset center, Offset coords) {
    var a = coords.dx - center.dx;
    var b = center.dy - coords.dy;
    return atan2(b, a);
  }
}
```

For drawing clock face

```
class ClockFaceComponent extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ClockFaceComponentState createState() {
    return new ClockFaceComponentState();
  }
}

class ClockFaceComponentState extends State<ClockFaceComponent> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: new AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 1.0,
        child: new Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: ColorResource.clockBackgroundColor,
          ),
          child: new Stack(
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: <Widget>[
              //dial and numbers
              new Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: double.infinity,
                child: new CustomPaint(
                  painter: new ClockDialPainter(),
                ),
              ),
              new Center(
                  child: new Container(
                width: 40.0,
                height: 40.0,
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              )),
              //centerpoint
              new Center(
                child: new Container(
                  width: 15.0,
                  height: 15.0,
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    color: ColorResource.clockCenterColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              getClockHands()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  getClockHands() {
    return new AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 1.0,
        child: new Stack(
          fit: StackFit.expand,
          children: getHands(),
        ));
  }

  getHands() {
    List<Widget> widgets = new List();
    List<Hands> hands = Hands.getHands();
    for (Hands hand in hands) {
      widgets.add(ClockHandComponent(
        title: hand.title,
        time: hand.time,
        color: hand.color,
      ));
    }

    return widgets;
  }
}
```

Comment: added the code of clock hand and clock face added